# cannot request Django URL

Tags: python, django

l have two url patterns in my Django

```
url(r'^myakun', 'portal.views.myakun', name='myakun'),
url(r'^myakun/about/$', 'portal.views.myakun_about', name='myakun_about'),
```

when l request to **www.site.com/myakun** it work well, but when I request to **www.site.com/myakun/about/** it will force to redirect to **www.site.com/myakun**

this is my views

```
def myakun(request):
    __return render_to_response("myakun.html", locals())        

def myakun_about(request):
    __return HttpResponse("sdasda")
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch order of your urls like

```
url(r'^myakun/about/$', 'portal.views.myakun_about', name='myakun_about'), 
url(r'^myakun', 'portal.views.myakun', name='myakun'),
```

In your case `http://www.site.com/myakun/about/` matches with first url pattern `^myakun` and hence shows your that page.

Or change the url pattern to add `$`

```
    url(r'^myakun/$', 'portal.views.myakun', name='myakun'),
```

Answer (score 0):

This url:

```
url(r'^myakun', 'portal.views.myakun', name='myakun'),
```

Should be:

```
url(r'^myakun/$', 'portal.views.myakun', name='myakun'),
```

Note the `EOL` matching `$` added in. The problem is without that '^myakun' matches '/myakun/about' and that view is returned, it never even checks to see if '^myakun/about' matches, even though it does indeed match as well.